# Backbone: restore model's attributes value after a failed save with patch:true

Tags: backbone.js, model

I have a big doubt about my implementation of a model's save via form in backbone using the patch HTTP method.

My problem is that if the server return an error, at the next save backbone will send an empty object as data because the values are already been set on the model and so they are not changing again.

My code looks like that:

```
var data = $('#form').serialize();

this.model.set(data);
var attr = (this.model.hasChanged()) ? this.model.changedAttributes() : {};

this.model.save(attr,{patch: true, wait: true, error: function(model, xhr, options){
    model.set(model.previousAttributes(),{silent: true});
}});
```

I've managed to "resolve" this by re-setting the attributes of the model at their previous values but it don't feel right to me... Is there a better way to manage this case? If possible I would avoid to send the entire form data to the server every time! Thanks.

EDIT: a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMg4U/2/) that shows the problem, thanks to Creynders.

Comment: The problem really lies somewhere else, as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/creynders/JMg4U/1). Are you sure you're not calling `save` some place else too?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, anyway my situation is slightly different. My model has already its attributes, and I set their new values in the saveModel function, as you can see in this [edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMg4U/2/)

Comment: Ah yes, quite right! I agree this doesn't feel right, since it even behaves differently depending on whether it already had a value to begin with or not. A bug report is in order, IMO.

Comment: Actually I think there may be a flaw in my code: I call 'set' everytime I hit the save button, and so if the attributes are the same as the previous time it resets the changedAttributes array. So maybe I just have to call 'set' before 'save' only if user did actually edited some input in the form. I don't know if that's the right behaviour, tough.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit debatable what would be the "correct" behaviour.
You're right that it works fine if the data isn't set each time, though. See [edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/creynders/JMg4U/3/)

Comment: Yes, I see. I tried adding a "edited" properties to my view and setting it to true everytime a input field trigger a change event. When the user hits the save button model.set is called only if the edited properties it's true, and also set it to false so if the user don't make any further change model.set won't be called again. Sadly there is an edge case: if the user make an edit after a failed save and then revert it, the "edited" property became true but the values are the same and so nothing has changed for the model. I guess I'll stick to use previousAttributes() to revert the changes :\

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that your code can be simplified as follows:

```
var data = $('#form').serialize();
this.model.save(data ,{patch: true, wait: true});
```

Regarding to backbone [specifications](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save), `patch: true` is enough to send only changed attributes on server. `wait: true` promotes to not set model attributes in case of request failure. So, there is no need to set attributes before saving.

As a bonus, `save` method suggests model validation before sending request. So, model will not be changes in case of any validation errors. And you don't need to reset previous attributes.

Hope, I understand your problem properly.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. That was my initial tought too about the patch options, but if you try you'll see that it will send all the content of data, regardless if it has changed or not. From the official documentation:  "You'll get an HTTP PATCH request to the server **with just the passed-in attributes**."